# Fullpage.js autoheight fix slide in center of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js with `fp-auto-height` to ensure that the slide isn't full height of the screen, but when scrolling down it doesn't snap to the top.

I've created a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jw7enf9t/4/

You can see when you scroll the gap is at the top, I want the gap at the bottom, is this possible? I don't see any options to do this?

Any help would be grateful, all the best, Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's an open issue about it](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1854) in fullpage.js issues forum.

No solution was implemented yet. The default behavior of fullpage.js is the following one:

> fullPage.js will animate to the top if you come from a section above the destination one.
>   It will animate to the bottom if you come from a section below the destination one.

Why? Because the feature was originally though to be used for footers, and in that particular scenario this behavior is the expected one.